# Char array comparison

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to compare two arrays. Both of these arrays contain 15 characters. I want to see if they have the same element or not.

characters being read in to the array

Array1: ATGGAATTCTCGCTC

Array2: TTGGAATTCTAGCTC

These are both in the form of arrays and are being passed in as arrayt and arraymt. n_size and m_size are the size of each array.(this is because the arrays can be any length 1-15)

```
int mutations(char arrayt[],char arraymt[],int n_size,int m_size)
{
    int i=0,mutation=0;
    do{
        for(i=0;i<n_size;i++)
        {
            if (arrayt[i]==arraymt[i])
            {
                mutation=1;
            }
        }
    }while(n_size == m_size);
    return mutation;
}
```

This is the code I have so far for finding the differences in the two arrays. Problem is I don't know of a way that I can return if there is a difference for each of the elements. 1 is for a change and 0 is no change.

If anything is unclear let me know and I will try and clarify.

Comment: Have you considered using a `strcmp` for the comparison? Or you cannot use it because this is school assignment?

Comment: @AlokSave It is a school assignment. But doesn't <code>strcmp<code> return a single value? I need to record and print which elements do not match up.

Comment: By the looks of it, returning a differences array is the least of your problems right now. I hope it is clear that do-while loop will never terminate if  `n_size == m_size`, and if they're *not* equal, the *inner* for-loop is a recipe for undefined behavior.

Comment: @WhozCraig This a pretty simple fix. That's kinda from copy pasting previous code without checking.

Comment: What do you expect the result from two arrays in your question? Do you expect 9 which is length of first matched string "TGGAATTCT"?

Comment: @Fumu7 Well I would like get an array that contains 1 for matched and a 0 for mismatch so the resulting array should be
{0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1}

Comment: @user3482104: So pass in a third, empty array, and use that to store your values. You can't return arrays in C, so modifying a passed-in one is your only option.

Answer (score 0):

```
void mutations(char arrayt[],char arraymt[], int *result, int max_index)
{
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < max_index; i++)
  {
    if (arrayt[i] == arraymt[i])
    {
      result[i] = 0;
      continue;
    }
    else
    {
      result[i] = 1;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  int max_index;
  int *res;

  char arrayt[]  = "aabbccduu";
  char arraymt[] = "aabcccd";

  max_index = strlen(arrayt) <= strlen(arraymt) ? strlen(arrayt) : strlen(arraymt);

  res = calloc (1, sizeof(int) * max_index);
  if (res != NULL)
  {
    mutations(arrayt, arraymt, res, max_index);
    while (i < max_index)
    {
      printf("res[i] = %d\n", res[i]);
      i++;
    }

    free(res);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: But wont this stop at the very start and only return '1'? I need to know all of the mismatches and their indexes.

Comment: `sizeof arrayt` and `sizeof arraymt` will both be the same, the size of a `char *`: like 4 or 8.

Comment: @chux :   char a[] = "arjun";
  char b[] = "amd";

  printf("%d\n", sizeof a);
  printf("%d\n", sizeof b);  => gives 6 & 4 respectively.

Comment: @A.M.D Try that same `printf("%d\n", sizeof arrayt); printf("%d\n", sizeof arraymt);` inside `mutations()`rather than `main()`.  That is where code _had_ `int max_index = sizeof arrayt <= sizeof arraymt ? sizeof arrayt : sizeof arraymt;` and would serve little purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The code you required may be:

```
int* mutations(char arrayt[],char arraymt[],int n_size,int m_size)
{
    int i, size;
    int* mutation;

    // size = min(m_size,n_size)
    if n_size>m_size
       size=m_size;
    else
       size=n_size;
    endif

    mutation=*malloc( sizeof(int) * size); // allocate memory for return value


    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if (arrayt[i]==arraymt[i])
        {
            mutation[i]=1;
        } else {
            mutation[i]=0;
        }
     }

    return mutation;
}
```

Comment: 1) `mutation=*malloc( sizeof(int) * size);` should be `mutation = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);`  (no `*` before malloc) or better yet: `mutation = malloc(size * sizeof *mutation);`.  2) `if n_size>m_size` needs parens. 3) `endif`??

Answer (score 0):

Let's use 15 bits of an `unsigned` to record the results.

```
unsigned mutations(char arrayt[], char arraymt[], int n_size, int m_size) {
  int sizemin = min(n_size, m_size);
  int sizemax = max(n_size, m_size);
  unsigned dest = 0;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < sizemin; i++) {
    if (arrayt[i] == arraymt[i])
      dest |= 1 << i;
  }
  for (; i < sizemax; i++) {
    dest |= 1 << i;  // compares against empty values are set to 1
  }

  return dest;
}

void foo(void) {
  const char *Array1 = "ATGGAATTCTCGCTC";
  const char *Array2 = "TTGGAATTCTAGCTC";
  unsigned result = mutations(Array1, Array2, strlen(Array1), strlen(Array1));

  // LSBit contains the result of the compare of Array1[0] vs. Array1[1]
  printf("%X\n", result);
}
```